# qt stylesheet not working

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, stylesheet

So I am writing a small program,here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class CMyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,p = None):
        super(CMyWidget,self).__init__(p)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #w = QtWidgets.QWidget()   #this will be ok  #1
    w = CMyWidget()                              #2
    label = QtWidgets.QLabel(w)
    label.setText("12345")
    btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(w)
    btn.setText("X")

    hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(w)
    hlayout.addWidget(label)
    hlayout.addWidget(btn)
    w.setStyleSheet("border:none;"\
                "border-bottom:5px solid rgb(255,0,0)")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the problem is if i use `#1`,then everything is ok,all widgets's bottom border drawed;but if i change to `#2`,only child widget draw bottom border,the `CMyWidget` won't draw the bottom border,am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some problems with stylesheets when you try to use it in derived classes. To solve your problem, try to use this:

```
w = CMyWidget()    
w.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground)
```

In this code `QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground` means that widget should be drawn using a styled background.

Comment: thanks,that worked! i read the doc,it says the WA_StyledBackground:indicates the widget should be drawn using a styled background ,what does "a styled background" means? i am new in qt,and i am chinese,my poor english  just can't understand sentences

Comment: @user2689236 By default derived from QWidget classes ignore stylesheet, this attribute allows you to use (turn on) stylesheet.

Comment: i clicked the "this answer is useful",the page just poped "thanks for the feedback!once you earn a total of 15 reputation,your votes will change...",maybe i didn't have right to vote?

Comment: @user2689236 Currently you can't upvote answers, but it is not your fault, all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The way I use it and works is stating for what type of object is the style intended, in your case would be:

```
w.setStyleSheet( "QtWidgets.QWidget { border:none; border-bottom:5px solid rgb(255,0,0)}")
```

Comment: not working,if i change it to "QtWidgets.QWidget...",then all the widgets stop   draw the bottom border